# Image does not stay inline with text

Tags: html, css

I've just started using CSS to develop a web page.I got some code for the hover info feature, but when I apply it to my image and info, the image does not stay inline with the text, it is shifted down to almost it's own line. 
Here's the code:

in the header:

```
span.dropt {background: #ffeedd;}

span.dropt:hover {
    text-decoration: none; 
    background: #ffffff; 
    z-index: 6; 
}

span.dropt:hover span {left: 2%; background: #ffffff;} 

span.dropt span {
    position: absolute; left: -9999px;
    margin: 4px 0 0 0px; padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px; 
    border-style:solid; border-color:black; border-width:1px;
}

span.dropt:hover span {
    margin: 20px 0 0 170px; 
    background: #ffffff; 
    z-index:6;
}
```

In the body:

```
<div style="width:450px; margin:0 auto;">
    <font face = "impact" size = "6">
        <br>My text
        <span class="dropt"><img src = "questionmark.png"/>
           <span> My info text</span>
        </span><br>
    </font>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't use the `font` tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wESuL/1/)

In your css:

```
span.dropt{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Also, try not to do any inline styles eg:

```
<div style="width:450px;">
```

This is what a css file is for.

On another note, the `<font>` tag has been deprecated in HTML5. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font).

In my fiddle, I've updated your `css` slightly.

```
div{
    width:450px;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-family:"impact";
    font-size:28px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry I used the wrong element. I'm changed it now :) @user2879011

Answer (score 1):

You can add `display: inline-block` to your span:

```
span.dropt {
    background: #ffeedd;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Please note that `<font>` tag was deprecated since HTML 4, you should use `<span>` element instead.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9bc6d/1/)**

Comment: we're in sync @Felix :)

Comment: hes faster than me @BeatAlex hence why I up' vote him...swell of you to be detailed oriented..

Comment: As I said I was posting this while he was probably already finishing. I'll delete mines since its the same he should get the Answer that's for sure

Comment: thank you! good to know about font, I've just been looking through some tutorials, I guess they need to be updated!